# How to parse and translate a string with words that contain identical parts

Tags: javascript, algorithm, parsing, decode

I need to make a "decoder" type thing for a little game. It gives you a string like:

`eGgeggEGgO`

Which translates to "cat" because:

```
c = eGg  
a = egg  
t = EGgO
```

The problem is some of the words/letters have identical parts such as eGg and eGgo (K).

So theoretically I would imagine some type of "algorithm" that finds the "longest" match where it finds `eGg`, attempts `eGgo`, can't find it, and then it knows it's `C`.

The problem I have with this is that it's really not performant since it finds the first match and has to loop through all words to see if there's another match. Basically has to loop through all letters for every letter. I feel like there must be a better awy to handle that.

This is for the web and it could have a backend but hoping to just do it on the client so JavaScript is what I'm starting it in. I'm happy with a pseudo code version or JavaScript or some other language. I'm most stumped on the conceptual "how" than the actual coding it self.

UPDATE:

Here's the full map

```
  egg:  'A',
  Egg:  'B',
  eGg:  'C',
  EGg:  'D',
  egG:  'E',
  EgG:  'F',
  eGG:  'G',
  EGG:  'H',
  eggo: 'I',
  Eggo: 'J',
  eGgo: 'K',
  EGgo: 'L',
  egGo: 'M',
  EgGo: 'N',
  eGGo: 'O',
  EGGo: 'P',
  eggO: 'Q',
  EggO: 'R',
  eGgO: 'S',
  EGgO: 'T',
  egGO: 'U',
  EgGO: 'V',
  eGGO: 'W',
  EGGO: 'X',
  eggy: 'Y',
  eggs: 'Z'
```

Comment: Please show us the encoding algorithm, otherwise we have no way to help you. The example is not enough to understand how the encoding/decoding scheme works.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have a [prefix code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) it'll be hard to decode it, you might need backtracking, and you might not succeed at all.

Comment: Updated so it has the full mapping if that helps.

Comment: You can easily tokenise your input since all code symbols start with `e` but end with a different letter. No need to "*loop through all letters for every letter.*"

Comment: Oh that is a smart and, now that you mention it, obvious pattern to find the start. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tokenization problem, so we need a grammatical rule that for delimiting tokens.

Fortunately, every token begins with one of the cases of 'e', so it's all about finding e's and splitting just before them.

```js
const tokenMap = {
  egg:  'A',
  Egg:  'B',
  eGg:  'C',
  EGg:  'D',
  egG:  'E',
  EgG:  'F',
  eGG:  'G',
  EGG:  'H',
  eggo: 'I',
  Eggo: 'J',
  eGgo: 'K',
  EGgo: 'L',
  egGo: 'M',
  EgGo: 'N',
  eGGo: 'O',
  EGGo: 'P',
  eggO: 'Q',
  EggO: 'R',
  eGgO: 'S',
  EGgO: 'T',
  egGO: 'U',
  EgGO: 'V',
  eGGO: 'W',
  EGGO: 'X',
  eggy: 'Y',
  eggs: 'Z'
 }

const enciphered = 'eGgeggEGgO';
const tokens = enciphered.replace(/[e|E]/g, '^\$&');
const mappedTokens = tokens.split('^').map(key => tokenMap[key])
const deciphered = mappedTokens.join('')
console.log(deciphered)
```